# Como ignorar e não iterar sobre uma for em R

Tags: r

Estou usando esse comando para calcular 4 valores extraídos de um sumário da função sem (sem_smry). São realizadas 100 tentativas onde, caso relate erro, a tentativa é contada mas não computada. Preciso contar as tentativas "com erro" mas fazer com que esses erros não sejam armazenados numa matriz. Ao final a matriz deve conter 100 valores numéricos. Hoje a matriz guarda os valores obtidos e, nas tentativas erradas, guarda NA. Como posso pular as tentativas erradas, mas contar esses erros. O código abaixo é a parte do programa que conta as tentativas erradas e guarda os valores estimados, quando não dá erro.

```
  for (j in 1:length(pp)) {

  for (i in 1:100) {
    n0 <- sem_smry(dados, cfa, pp[j])
    if (any(class(n0) == "try-error")) {
      nnc[j] <- nnc[j] + 1
    } else  {
      RMSEA[i]<- n0[["RMSEA"]][1]
      NFI[i]<-n0[["NFI"]]
      GFI[i]<-n0[["GFI"]]
      CFI[i]<-n0[["CFI"]]
    }

    Indices <- cbind(RMSEA, GFI, NFI, CFI) 
}
```

[EDIT] Como pedido, vou explicar melhor o problema. Na execução do código anterior, o resultado da matriz é o seguinte:

```
  [1,] 0.12487090 0.7439197 0.8193802 0.9197872
  [2,] 0.05692412 0.8101720 0.8266571 0.9755843
  [3,] 0.11701959 0.7300448 0.7942616 0.9129401
  [4,] 0.10471572 0.7821648 0.8551393 0.9498845
  [5,] 0.09479998 0.7788558 0.8503112 0.9544811
  [6,] 0.13484758 0.7301779 0.7921450 0.8972345
  [7,] 0.12166489 0.7644818 0.8204229 0.9226289
  [8,] 0.10654332 0.7783956 0.8157848 0.9319917
  [9,] 0.19616764 0.6322465 0.6992935 0.8351372
 [10,]         NA        NA        NA        NA
 [11,] 0.17654647 0.6631480 0.7123008 0.8594085
 ...
```

Como é possível ver, na linha 10, a matriz guarda os valores de NA, no entanto, gostaria que o código não guardasse esses valores e sim, continuasse a execução do loop, guardando o valor de 11 em 10 e assim por diante mas ainda mantendo as 100 execuções esperadas para a iteração, o resultado esperado é uma matriz com os mesmos 100 valores da anterior mas apenas contendo apenas os números.

Anteriormente, dentro do IF do for tentei voltar a posição de i, caso acontecesse um problema usando i <= i - 1, para executar o loop e passar por cima dos valores de NA quando acontecem, mas não obtive sucesso.

Comment: A pergunta não está muito clara, e pelo que entendi, seu código parece funcionar como você deseja. Se quiser uma ajuda mais detalhada, terás que nos ajudar com a tua pergunta, explicando com mais detalhes os objetos do código e inserindo parte dos dados (`dput(head(dados))`).

Comment: Olá, acabei de editar a questão, espero que tenha ficado mais claro o problema.

Comment: Experimente imediatamente a seguir ao `} else {` por `if(is.na(n0[["RMSEA"]][1])) next`.

Answer (score 2):

Você pode usar a opção `while()` no sentido que vai tentar várias vezes até não obter um erro, mantendo o valor de `i` fixo:

```
for (j in 1:length(pp)) {

  for (i in 1:100) {

    n0 <- sem_smry(dados, cfa, pp[j])

    while (any(class(n0) == "try-error")) {
      nnc[j] <- nnc[j] + 1
      n0 <- sem_smry(dados, cfa, pp[j])
    }

    RMSEA[i]<- n0[["RMSEA"]][1]
    NFI[i]<-n0[["NFI"]]
    GFI[i]<-n0[["GFI"]]
    CFI[i]<-n0[["CFI"]]

    Indices <- cbind(RMSEA, GFI, NFI, CFI) 
  }
}
```